# Из всех тридцать одн? сообщений только перв(ое/ые) двадцать одн? был(о/и) по существу

Tags: грамматика

What endings should I choose when I am talking about quantities equal to 21 + 10n?

> Вчера в ответ на свою статью получил аж тридцать одно сообщение.
>   Думал, что все они будут о моей статье, но оказалось не так – из все(х/го)
>   тридцать одн? прибывш(ий/их) сообщени(й/я) только перв(ое/ые) двадцать одн? был(о/и) по
>   существу, остальные же можно было бы и не читать.
>
> Судейская коллегия состояла из двадцать одн? суд(ей/ьи). Случай был
>   уникальный. Впервые за всю историю нашего существования среди судей
>   царило полное согласие. Все двадцать одн? присутствоваш(ий/ие) судь? был? абсолютно
>   согласны друг с другом.

EDIT:
added "прибывш(ий/их)" and "присутствоваш(ий/ие)" to my examples.

EDIT:
placed "прибывш(ий/их)" and "присутствоваш(ий/ие)" right before the nouns that they are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the rule, but this one sounds about right:

> Вчера в ответ на свою статью получил аж тридцать одно сообщение.
>   Думал, что все они будут о моей статье, но оказалось не так – из
>   всех тридцати одного сообщения только первые двадцать одно
>   были по существу, остальные же можно было бы и не читать.
>
> Судейская коллегия состояла из двадцати одного судьи. Случай был
>   уникальный. Впервые за всю историю нашего существования среди судей
>   царило полное согласие. Все двадцать один судья были абсолютно
>   согласны друг с другом.

Answer (score 6):

The rules are different for the 10n part and for the 1 part of the numerals.

The 10n part changes in the same way it usually changes (for a proper description see [here](http://masterrussian.com/aa050601a.shtml) or your peferred grammar reference book).

The noun should be singular and in the case that matches its grammatical function in the sentence (e.g. nominative for the subject, accusative for the direct object, etc.)

The 1 part you need to put in the form that matches the case, the number and the gender of the following noun.

Here are 3 examples from your text:

> 1. Я получил тридцать одно сообщение
> 2. Из тридцати одного сообщения только первые двадцать одно были по существу.
> 3. Двадцать один судья были согласны друг с другом

In example 1., "сообщение" is of neutral gender and occupies the position of a direct object, which means it needs to be in the accusative case (that matches the form of the nominative case, since "сообщение" is inanimate).

In example 2., you get the genitive case with the preposition "из" and the nominative case for the subject.

In example 3., you get the nominative again, because the word "судья" is the subject.

In all examples, the nouns are in singular.

May I just note that your question looks like you're seeking someone to do a whole exercise for you. I believe that it is frown upon here and you shouldn't do it again.

Comment: "May I just note that your question looks like you're seeking someone to do a whole exercise for you. I believe that it is frown upon here and you shouldn't do it again" - What exactly should I not do again?

Comment: I think she means don't ask about what seems like an entire exercise.  (And, by the way, there is no such word as одн.)

Comment: @Kcd - Thanks, but I would want to hear an answer directly from her.

Comment: @Kcd - "(And, by the way, there is no such word as одн.)" - Sure, but you do have such words like "одного" and "одних", though. I wrote "одн?", not "одн."

Comment: KCd is right, this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Olga: you have masterfully omitted "Всех/всего". Try include it into your examples and try to apply the rules you have mentioned

Comment: @Olga: "KCd is right, this is exactly what I meant" - So I should not ask again a question that might look as an exercise. But how can I predict whether or not my question will look to someone as an exercise? I had no idea that my question could look to someone that way when I was asking it.

Comment: @cha I omitted quantifiers because the question was not about them. If I were you, I'd ask about "все\всех" in another question.

Comment: @brilliant Don't post an exercise and ask people to fill in the endings. Post a question and an example where you have problems.

Comment: @Olga - "Don't post an exercise and ask people to fill in the endings" - When did I post an exercise?!!!! The way things look to you may not always be the way things are, you know. I myself made up all the examples to illustrate the question that I was asking (which is, what endings I should use in words when talking about quantities equal to 21 + 10n). Where did you see an exercise? "Post a question and an example where you have problems" - Which is exactly what I did.

Comment: @Olga - "I omitted quantifiers because the question was not about them" - How was my question not about them?!!! I think I made it quite clear in my first example that choosing between "всех" and "всего", that is, choosing between "-ех" and "-его" endings for the quantifier was part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Вчера в ответ на свою статью получил аж тридцать одно сообщение. Думал, что все они будут о моей статье, но оказалось не так – из всех прибывших тридцать одного сообщения только первые двадцать одно были по существу, остальные же можно было бы и не читать.

Судейская коллегия состояла из двадцать одного судьи. Случай был уникальный. Впервые за всю историю нашего существования среди судей царило полное согласие. Все присутствовашие двадцать один судья были абсолютно согласны друг с другом.

Comment: Желательно объяснить почему выбраны именно такие окончания. Это ведь не сайт правильных ответов на контрольные работы или тесты.

Comment: "из всех прибывших тридцать одного сообщения" - Why not "тридцати"?

Comment: @brilliant looks like a copy/paste error to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better workaround these constructions, as even as a native, I don't know how to write it correct, and either way I can imagine doesn't sound good. What seems to be grammatically correct is `из всего тридцати одного прибывшего сообщения`, `только первое двадцать одно было...` and `Все двадцать один присутствоваший судья были...`. But stylistically it still sounds bad.
To tell what endings need to be used you need to disassemble the sentence. For example, let's do it with `из все(х/го) тридцать одн? прибывш(ий/их) сообщени(й/я)`. First you take `из тридцать одн? -> из тридцати + из одного = из тридцати одного` next you add `все(х/го)`. We have "one", so it will be `всего`, like in `всего один`.
This far we have `из всего тридцати одного прибывш(ий/их) сообщени(й/я)` and again, we have this "one" thing (yeah, it is confusing), so we write `прибывшего` and `сообщения`

More stylistically nice would be something like:

> Вчера в ответ на свою статью получил аж тридцать одно сообщение. Думал, что все они будут о моей статье, но оказалось не так – из всех прибывших сообщений только двадцать одно было по существу, остальные же можно было бы и не читать.
>
> Судейская коллегия состояла из двадцати одного судьи. Случай был уникальный. Впервые за всю историю нашего существования среди судей царило полное согласие. Все присутствовашие судьи были абсолютно согласны друг с другом.